# undefined index:action shown in php page called through ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Whenever i am calling a function in js the ajax call and php page give me an error of undefined index action.can anyone tell me how to solve this error.

Here is my code of js:

```
function fetch_user()
{ $.ajax({
 url:"chat_action.php",
method:"POST",
data:{'action':fetch_user},
dataType:'Json',
success:function(data){
   console.log(data);
$('#user_details').html(data);
 }
})
}
```

and php code is:

```
<?php
include ('Chat.php');
$chat = new Chat();
if($_POST['action'] == 'fetch_user') {
$chat->fetch_user($_SESSION['user_id']);
}
?>
```

the chat.php has a function which fetched data from database

Comment: Should the quotes be there around `action`, wouldn't it be `data:{action: 'fetch_user'},` instead? What do you get if you `var_dump($_POST);` in your PHP code?

Comment: i am getting this on var_dump 'action' => string 'fetch_user' (length=10) also i have removed quotes and put them around fetch user

Comment: is it `object` or `array` ?

Comment: it is an array..

Comment: i have made some silly mistakes now i have corrected them and my code is working fine..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am execute your above given code and done some modifications.

**My Js Code**

```
$.ajax({
        url:"data.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{action:'fetch_user'},
        dataType:'Json',
        success:function(data){
          console.log(data);
          $('#user_details').html(data);
        }
      });
```

**MY php code**

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
die;
```

**My Output in console**

```
Array
(
    [action] => fetch_user
)
```